# Why is not the same between query in php and query in SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cakephp

I have a CakePHP project with a SQL server, but I am confused when running this query:

```
result = $this->Manager->query('SELECT TOP(10) name, id
                                            FROM vendors
                                            WHERE name LIKE N\'%'.$q.'%\'');
```

When I set  `$q = 'Hòa'` and  run this SQL script in SQL management studio, it returns 2 result, but when run in PHP it returns nothing,

Comment: If you hard code the value instead of using a variable in php, do you get the 2 records?  Not related to your problem, but a top n query without an order by clause looks dicey.

Comment: Yup, when i hard code and don't use variable in php. It is still returned no result!

Comment: $result = array() with nothing in that

Comment: If you enable debug, what does your SQL debug panel show? Does it show the *exact* query you're running in SQL Studio? Do other queries work normally using that model?

Comment: @HòaĐinh . . . Two possibilities I can readily think of.  (1) You are connected to the wrong database.  (2) Your query string and/or $q variable is using narrow characters instead of unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
result = $this->Manager->query("SELECT TOP(10) name, id
                                            FROM vendors
                                            WHERE name LIKE N'%".$q."%'");
```